# How to stop running uTorrent in Ubuntu18.04.1?

Tags: 18.04, utorrent

After following this installation guide:
https://idroot.us/linux/install-utorrent-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

I'm curious if there is a way to undo

```
utserver -settingspath/opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/&
```

What I also wanted to achieve here is that when a user is done using uTorrent, it should no longer be running and it should be inaccessible to the browser (localhost:8080/gui must return an error 404).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
sudo pkill utserver
```